# Integration tests work in maven but not in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, junit, integration-testing

Whenever I run my tests in maven with mvn clean install it works fine, however trying to run the tests in Eclipse with "run as/JUnit test" on /src/test-integration/java, the .java file or the method.

The JUnit window in Eclipse shows it's running 1/25 but it does not seem go anywhere but the processor is running high.

[image]

When looking in the debug view I can see

[image]

Also, it works for some collegues but we don't know why, any ideas?

EDIT:
Thanks to @Aaron Digulla I now know where it hangs:

It hangs at `ResourceDatabasePopulator.splitSqlScript(String String, List<String>)` and the only variables increasing are `sb` and `i` (`StringBuilder id`, and loopcounter?). (sb id=101 right now and i = 712107) Anyone have an idea of why it works in maven but not in Eclipse?

Comment: You can try to run the test in the debugger. Then switch to the Debug Perspective and pause the whole process. Next, look into the stack of the main thread to see where it hangs.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Thanks, updated question with details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the JRE in Eclipse to 1.6, probably because of this bug:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9781

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a bug in `ResourceDatabasePopulator.splitSqlScript` which causes it to go into an endless loop. You'll have to debug the code to find out why it happens.